# $f: A \rightarrow B$, $g: B \rightarrow A$, $A' = Ran(g)$, $f \circ g = i_B$. Prove $f \restriction A'$ is a one-to-one and onto.

Tags: functions, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> $f: A \rightarrow B$, $g: B \rightarrow A$, $A' = Ran(g)$, $f \circ g
>  = i_B$
>
> Prove that $f \restriction A'$ is a one-to-one, onto function from
>   $A'$ to $B$ and $g = (f \restriction A')^{-1}$

My attempt:

Notation:

$$f \restriction A' = f \cap (A' \times B)$$

$$i_B = \{(b,b) \mid b \in B\}$$

> **Lemma 1.** Suppose $a \in A'$ . Then $\forall b \in B \bigl((a,b) \in f \iff (b,a) \in g \bigr)$

Take arbitrary $a \in A'$

Suppose $b \in B$ such that $(a,b) \in f$. Since $a \in Ran(g)$, then exists $d \in B$ such that $(d,a) \in g$. Then we have $(d,b) \in i_B$ which means that $d = b$. And therefore $(b,a) \in g$

Suppose $b \in B$ such that $(b,a) \in g$. Then $(b,b) \in i_B$. Exists $d$ such that $(b,d) \in g$ and $(d,b) \in f$. $d = a$ and $(a,b) \in f$.

---

Proof of the proposition:

> $f \restriction A' : A' \rightarrow B$

Existence: Take $a \in A'$. Exists $b \in B$ such that $(a,b) \in f$. We also have $(a,b) \in A' \times B$ and thus $(a,b) \in f \restriction A'$

Uniqueness: Suppose $(a,b_1),(a,b_2) \in f \restriction A'$. We have $(a,b_1),(a,b_2) \in f$ and thus $b_1 = b_2$

> $f \restriction A'$ is an injection

Take $(a_1,b),(a_2,b) \in f \restriction A' $. Then both are in $f$ and $a_1,a_2 \in A'$. By lemma 1 we conclude that $(b,a_1),(b,a_2) \in g$ and since $g$ is a function, $a_1=a_2$.

> $f \restriction A'$ is a surjection

Take $b \in B$. Exists $a \in A'$ such that $(b,a) \in g$. By lemma 1, we have $(a,b) \in f$, and since $(a,b) \in A' \times B$, $(a,b) \in f \restriction A'$

> $g = (f \restriction A')^{-1}$

Take $(b,a) \in g$. By lemma 1, $(a,b) \in f$. We also have $(a,b) \in A ' \times B$. Hence $(a,b) \in f \restriction A'$ and $(b,a) \in (f \restriction A')^{-1}$

Take $(b,a) \in (f \restriction A')^{-1}$. Then $(a,b) \in f \restriction A'$, and by lemma 1 we have $(b,a) \in g$.

We have our result:  $g = (f \restriction A')^{-1}$

$\Box$

Is it correct?